# How do I identify a circular reference in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, circular-dependency

#### Scenario

I'm having a problem where a Terraform module has defined the SQS queue and its policy within, but I'm getting the following error when trying to run terraform plan, apply and even refresh. Why?

#### Error

```
The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument
```

#### User code

```
module "my_sqsqueue" {
  source = "[redacted]"
  sqs_name = "${local.some_name}"
  sqs_policy        = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "my_policy",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "111",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "${module.my_sqsqueue.sqs_queue_arn}",
        "Condition": {
          "ArnEquals": {
            "aws:SourceArn": "[redacted]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

#### Module definition

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "main_queue_policy" {
  count = var.sqs_policy != "" ? 1 : 0

  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.main_queue.id
  policy    = var.sqs_policy
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "main_queue" {
  content_based_deduplication       = var.sqs_content_based_deduplication
  delay_seconds                     = var.sqs_delay_seconds
  fifo_queue                        = var.sqs_fifo_queue
  kms_data_key_reuse_period_seconds = var.sqs_kms_data_key_reuse_period_seconds
  kms_master_key_id                 = var.sqs_kms_master_key_id
  max_message_size                  = var.sqs_max_message_size
  message_retention_seconds         = var.sqs_message_retention_seconds
  name                              = var.sqs_name
  receive_wait_time_seconds         = var.sqs_receive_wait_time_seconds
  visibility_timeout_seconds        = var.sqs_visibility_timeout_seconds

  tags = merge(
    {
      Name = var.sqs_name
    },
    local.default_tag_map
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message here, including the contextual information like the source code snippet and which values were in scope? The code example you shared doesn't include a `count` argument, so I have to assume that the error message is talking about something other than the code example, and it would help to see specifically what Terraform is referring to in order to give a concrete answer.

Comment: I'd love some assistance here. The issue is the circular reference, and that's what I wanted to focus on. Terraform is unable to resolve this automatically, and provides misleading errors hiding the true cause.

Answer (score 0):

The `Resource` attribute on the `sqs_policy` is referencing an output field of the `my_sqsqueue` module, but that module itself is dependent on the `sqs_policy`.

So, either:

1. Temporarily remove the circular reference, setting the `sqs_policy` attribute to `""`, apply and then return the reference and apply again.
2. Manually define the reference if possible. Here, with AWS ARNs, that is possible, but this isn't always the case.